# I get the error that my View did not return a HttpResponse Object. It returned none

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
def my_view(request, my_id):
    myItem = Item.objects.get(pk=item_id)
    context = {'myitem': my item}
    #This is where I send a POST request from a button named myButton with a value="OK".
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'OK' in request.POST:
            return render(request, 'url1', context)`enter code here`
    else:
        return render(request, 'url2', context)
```

Above is my code. If I get `request.POST` to print, it actually has the value OK in the dictionary. And yet, Python doesn't execute the if clause.

Output of the `request.POST`   is :

```
<QueryDict: {u'submit': [u'OK'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'#####']}>
```

Comment: Please show the output of request.POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `request.POST` has dictionary structure; it has key and value. Assuming that `request.POST` has `{'key': 'OK'}`, the conditional statement would be appropriate if

```
if request.POST['key'] == 'OK':
```

or this would be better

```
if request.POST.get('key') == 'OK':
```

because `request.POST.get` gives `None` if it has no such key.

Comment: Hi Leonard2, there is a key in the request.POST. In fact, the exact same scenario worked with a different form and a view. It is just not working here.

Comment: There may be other issues, but `'OK' in request.POST` will result in `False`. You can check that `'val' in {'key': 'val'}` gives `False`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for your solutions, I will implement it that way and accept the answer if it works. On a separate note, so when can I use the if 'val' in request.POST conditional?

Comment: On the other way, please note that `'key' in {'key': 'val'}` becomes `True`. So I can tell that such conditional can be used if you want to check the `request.POST` has such key, not value. Also on a separate note too, your `request.POST` output seems to have a list as a value of 'submit', is that correct? Hope this helps:)

Comment: Oh I see! Perhaps that's why, in my earlier implementation my key and value both had the same name. Thanks. 'submit' is the name of the button that is sending the value 'OK'. So I thought 'submit' is the key for the value 'OK'.

Comment: very glad it did help//// the name attribute of input is the key of POST, you're right.

Comment: If you know just how much you helped :) I will be more mindful with handling the forms in the views now on. Thanks so much!